# Flutter App the Phone Navigatio Bar not showing?

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter app the navigation bar of my Phone is not showing (clock, signal, batery)?
Thats in the Emulator and Phone, both Android.

Thx!

Comment: Try to wrap the Scaffold with ```SafeArea() Widget```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

1. wrap your code in safe area

if step 1 is not working then

do

```html
AppBar(
  backwardsCompatibility: false,
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.orange),
)
```